# Shopping cart sorting

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart, sorting

In the shopping cart we need to sort products in the order they are added and the grouped products need to be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Any possibility to include the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 11):

We'll need to fix this in 2 parts. The first part is actually tracking which simple products in the cart come from grouped products. The second is the sorting.

First for the tracking. We'll add an extra column in `sales_flat_quote_item` to store that information.

To do this properly write your own module, a tutorial about that you can find here on [Tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643).

You'll also need an install script. Check out this [Inchoo tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/) about that.

Add the following in your install script

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->addAttribute('quote_item', 'is_grouped', array(
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
    'visible'  => false,
    'required' => false,
    'default'  => 0
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

This will be a simple **0** or **1** value.

Now we need to set that value when a product is added to the cart.
We can do this with an observer.

Add the following in your `config.xml`

```
<sales_quote_item_set_product>
    <observers>
        <[namespace]_[module]_sales_quote_item_set_product>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>salesQuoteItemSetProduct</method>
        </[namespace]_[module]_sales_quote_item_set_product>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_item_set_product>
```

Now we need to know when added to cart this was a grouped product. We'll do that with a simple input field in the *add to cart form*.

Add the following in your modules layout XML. It will add an input field when the product type is grouped.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
        <reference name="product_options_wrapper">
            <block type="core/text" name="isgrouped.input">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<input type="hidden" name="isgrouped" value="1"/>]]></text></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```

And an observer class that checks for the presence of the input.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesQuoteItemSetProduct($o)
    {
        $this->_setIsGrouped($o);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _setIsGrouped($o)
    {
        $isGrouped = (int)$this->getRequest()->getPost('isgrouped');
        if ($isGrouped) {
            $quoteItem = $o->getQuoteItem();
            $quoteItem->setIsGrouped($isGrouped);
        }
    }
}
```

This will set the table field `is_grouped` to 1 when the simple product originates from a grouped product.

Now on to the sorting! The block class behind the cart is `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` which we'll need to rewrite from our own module. You can do that by adding the following to the `config` > `global` tag in your `config.xml`

```
<blocks>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <cart>[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Checkout_Cart</cart>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

And the `getItems` method can now filter out the grouped items and filter those alphabetically

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Checkout_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart
{

    /**
     * Return customer quote items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomItems()) {
            return $this->getCustomItems();
        }

        $grouped = [];
        $items = parent::getItems();

        /**
         * Filter all the grouped items out to sort them
         */
        foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
            if ($item->getIsGrouped() == 1) {
                $grouped["{$item->getName()}{$item->getId()}"] = $item;
                unset($items[$i]);
            }
        }

        ksort($grouped, SORT_STRING); // sort key (which is name) alphabetically

        return array_merge($grouped, $items);
    }
}
```

*DISCLAIMER: untested code so might need some tweaking here or there but it should work in general. If not just comment*

Comment: Leaving it as a comment for now: you can achieve the same without adding a new field, because the data is already saved in the [`info_buyRequest`](http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/09/magento-info_buyrequest-objekt-referenz/) option: `$groupedId = $item->getBuyRequest()->getData('super_product_config')['product_id']`

Comment: enjoy those sweet sweet internet points Mr. Mangelbangel

Comment: @benmarks https://media.giphy.com/media/X8omQqfFyeq1a/giphy.gif